# Why is the Upload option not showing up?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

[image: This is a screen-shot from the AppConnect Page for my App]

This is a screen-shot from the AppConnect Page for my app. I have archieved my build from Xcode, validated it and even distributed it from the window that pops up after archiving. I have waited for sometime for the upload to show up on AppConnect but for some reason it just shows See Upload Tools, my Xcode is also fully updated. What can I do to upload my build to AppConnect?

Hope you can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **Activity** tab in App Store Connect and check what's the status of the build.

The uploaded build has to finish processing from Apple side, which **might take time** depending on the load. You might have to set export compliance and other stuffs when asked before choosing the build.

You'll get an email from App Store Connect once the processing has finished for the uploaded binary. After that, the **"⨁"** button will get enabled.